# I'm learning C++ ,should I Use the latest compiler versions or the one which my university uses?

Tags: c++, version

I see that there is quite a bit of difference in the syntaxes of newer versions of compilers.
For example, a syntax that works on c++11 doesn't work on c++98.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
// Create a vector containing integers
std::vector<int> v = {7, 5, 16, 8};

// Add two more integers to vector
v.push_back(25);
v.push_back(13);

// Iterate and print values of vector
for(int n : v) {
    std::cout << n << '\n';
}
}
```

the above syntax of for() loop doesn't work on c+++98.
Also, the vector IN c++98 needs to be initialized first using a constructor.
So, should I use the latest versions of the compiler, or stick to the one that my teachers are using?

Comment: Basically, use latest versions if you want to learn up-to-date C++; use non-latest versions if you want to learn obsolete C++.  Sometimes you need to conform to school restrictions (which unfortunately is not something you can easily fix), but in general, try to use latest versions and learn modern C++.

Comment: I'd say choosing between learning a 22year old version of the language or the current version, should be easy.

Comment: You should learn the more recent Standards, but you also have to pass your classes, and you probably can't do that if you start dropping lambdas, concepts, and range-based for on your poor marker's head. The course syllabus just wasn't built for it. Learn both.

Comment: It depends on your objective.   If your objective is to pass a course being taught by the university, or to write code that can be built/used by the university, then it is better to use the same version of compilers as the university.  You don't gain much by submitting code that will earn a fail if it is rejected by the university's compiler, particularly if that is made clear to you before submitting the code.  Even professionals need to accept being constrained to use old technology sometimes, and learn how to deal with that.

Comment: C++98 and C++11 are language versions not compiler versions. There is absolutely no reason to downgrade your compiler even if you do want to restrict yourself to C++98. Just specify `std=c++98` as an argument to GCC or Clang and they will only accept C++98.

Comment: thank you @sepp2k for clarifying that :)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to even use the c++98 compilers ?
C++ has evolved to a great extent now.
You should use the newest compilers to be up-to-date with the language.
There are many robust features which were not present at the time of c++98.
Therefore, you should use the newest compilers for learning.

Comment: Use the newest **compilers** for learning. The choice of an IDE or a text editor and command line is orthogonal. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have an explicit reason to use an outdated version of C++, use the newest standard that's implemented for your compiler, as of now that's C++ 17 for gcc, clang amd msvc, C++20 is WiP.